# Pilha dinâmica - Comparar valores

Tags: c++

Olá, tudo bem?
Então, eu precisava fazer uma função em uma pilha dinâmica para testar se duas pilhas contendo números inteiros são iguais, ou seja, para ver se dois valores são possuem o mesmo conteúdo e na mesma ordem.
Por enquanto o que eu tenho é esse código, que empilha, desempilha e exibe valores, mas ainda falta a função de comparar. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/// Estrutura TipoPilha
typedef struct {
    char letra;     
}TipoItem;
typedef struct TipoCelula *TipoApontador; 
typedef struct TipoCelula {
    TipoItem Item;
    TipoApontador Prox;
} TipoCelula; 
typedef struct { 
    TipoApontador Fundo, Topo; 
    int Tamanho; 
} TipoPilha;

// Funções de manipulação da pilha
void FPVazia(TipoPilha *Pilha) {
    Pilha ->Topo=(TipoApontador) malloc(sizeof(TipoCelula ));
    Pilha ->Fundo = Pilha ->Topo;
    Pilha ->Topo->Prox = NULL;
    Pilha ->Tamanho;
}

int Vazia(TipoPilha Pilha) {
    return (Pilha.Topo == Pilha.Fundo);
}

void Empilha(TipoItem x, TipoPilha *Pilha) {
    TipoApontador Aux; 
    Aux = (TipoApontador) malloc(sizeof(TipoCelula)); 
    Pilha->Topo->Item = x; 
    Aux->Prox = Pilha ->Topo; 
    Pilha ->Topo = Aux; 
    Pilha ->Tamanho++; 
}

void Desempilha(TipoPilha *Pilha , TipoItem *Item) {
    TipoApontador q; 
    if (Vazia(*Pilha ) ) { 
        printf ( "Erro : lista vazia\n" ) ; return; 
    }
    q = Pilha ->Topo; 
    Pilha ->Topo = q ->Prox; 
    *Item = q ->Prox->Item; 
    free(q) ;
    Pilha ->Tamanho--; 
}

int Tamanho(TipoPilha Pilha) {
    return (Pilha.Tamanho) ;
}

void ExibePilha(TipoPilha Pilha){
    TipoApontador aux=Pilha.Topo->Prox;
    while(aux!=NULL){
        printf("\n %c", aux->Item.letra);
        aux=aux->Prox;
    }
}

main(){
    TipoPilha pilha;
    FPVazia(&pilha);
    TipoItem item;
    int op=-1;
    while(op!=0){
        printf("\n0- Sair");
        printf("\n1- Empilha");
        printf("\n2- Desempilha");
        printf("\n3- Exibe a pilha");
        printf("\nDigite sua opcao: "); scanf("%d", &op);
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                printf("Digite a letra a ser empilhada: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%c", &item.letra);
                Empilha(item, &pilha);
            break;
            case 2:
                Desempilha(&pilha, &item);
                printf("\nItem desempilhado: %c", item.letra);
            break;
            case 3:
                printf("\n*** Exibindo a pilha*** \n");
                ExibePilha(pilha);
            break;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro verifique se elas têm tamanhos iguais, se não tiver você já sabe que são diferentes. Se forem iguais então você precisa desempilhar os elementos das duas pilhas e comparar os valores. Exemplo:

```
bool igual = true;
int elemento1, elemento2;

while(/* Repetir até a pilha ficar vazia */)
{
    desempilhar(pilha1, &elemento1);
    desempilhar(pilha2, &elemento2);

    if(elemento1 != elemento2) igual = false;
}
```

Se tiver um elemento diferente então `igual` será falso ao fim do loop. Com isso você já consegue comparar, o problema é que as pilhas ficarão vazias, para resolver isso você pode usar duas pilhas auxiliares ou usar recursividade e assim poder empilhar os elementos novamente.

**Exemplo com duas pilhas auxiliares**

Talvez a forma mais intuitiva é fazer algo assim:

```
while(/* Repetir até a pilha ficar vazia */)
{
    desempilhar(pilha1, &elemento1);
    desempilhar(pilha2, &elemento2);

    if(elemento1 != elemento2) igual = false;

    empilhar(&aux1, elemento1);
    empilhar(&aux2, elemento2);
}

while(/* Repetir até a pilha ficar vazia */)
{
    desempilhar(&aux1, &elemento1);
    desempilhar(&aux2, &elemento2);

    empilhar(pilha1, elemento1);
    empilhar(pilha2, elemento2);
}
```

**Exemplo com recursividade**

Podemos percorrer uma `pilha` usando o seguinte exemplo:

```
void pecorrerPilha(Pilha *pilha)
{
    int elemento;

    desempilhar(pilha, &elemento);

    if(/* Se não tiver vazia */) pecorrerPilha(pilha);

    empilhar(pilha, elemento);
}
```

Usando essa lógica você pode evitar ter mais duas pilhas auxiliares e assim o código ficará mais elegante. Exemplo:

```
int elemento1, elemento2;

desempilhar(pilha1, &elemento1);
desempilhar(pilha2, &elemento2);

if(elemento1 != elemento2) *igual = false;

if(/* Se não tiver vazia */ && *igual) pecorrerPilha(pilha1, pilha2, igual);

empilhar(pilha1, elemento1);
empilhar(pilha2, elemento2);
```

Usando a recursividade você pode usar um ponteiro para que a alteração do valor `igual` seja em todas, evitando assim que a alteração fique apenas em um único escopo.